# How to mask widgets with rounded corners on scroll - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

How do you make the top section where the widgets scroll and disappear on top has rounded corners so it seems natural?

To make it clearer, here's what I tried to do but didn't work:

|  |
| --- |
| [image: example] |

The idea is to make the blue-colored section in the middle transparent to show the widgets when it scrolls to disappear while having rounded corners to keep the design language consistent. But so far, if I were to remove the blue color, the widgets would just disappear on the line like how it is with color.

I tried to use WidgetMask and ClipPath but it didn't work like in the example.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)